# Prove or disprove : there exist at most two root of $f(x)=f'(x)$.

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ be differentiable over $[0,+\infty)$, and $f'(x)$ be
>   increasing and convex over $[0,+\infty).$ If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then
>   there exist at most two roots of $f(x)=f'(x)$ over $[0,+\infty).$

Apparently, $x=0$ is already a root, hence we only need prove there exists at most one nonzero root else. Maybe we may construct an auxiliary function $F(x):=e^{-x}f(x)$, then $F'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$. This will help? Besides, notice that we are **not** told that $f''(x)$ exists.

Comment: Sounds like an intermediate value theorem problem to me. The auxiliary function you have constructed is also an interesting idea.

Comment: I think that the idea of the auxiliary function requires implementing the key fact that $f'$ is increasing and concave. Since there is no access to $f''$ I think that a key part of the problem is reformulating concaveness just in terms of $f$ and $f'$. I think that $f'$ increasing and concave and $f'(c)=f(c)$ implies $f'(x)>f(x)$ for $x>c$ but no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there exists $0 < a < b$ such that $f(a) = f'(a)$ and $f(b) = f'(b)$.

Since $f'$ is concave we have

$$\frac{f'(b) - f'(a) }{b-a} < \frac{f'(b)-f'(0)}{b-0}< \frac{f'(a)-f'(0)}{a-0}=\frac{f'(a)}{a}$$

Since $f'$ is increasing, $f$ is convex and

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > \frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0}= \frac{f(a)}{a}$$

Thus, we arrive at a contradiction

$$\frac{f(a)}{a} < \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{f'(b) - f'(a) }{b-a} < \frac{f'(a)}{a} = \frac{f(a)}{a}$$

Edit: The original question included the assumption that $f’$ is concave.

Comment: sir, it should be $$\frac{f'(b) - f'(a) }{b-a} > \frac{f'(b)-f'(0)}{b-0}> \frac{f'(a)-f'(0)}{a-0}=\frac{f'(a)}{a}$$?

Comment: Since $f′$ is increasing, $f$ is concave.

Comment: @mengdie1982: See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Function_is_Convex_iff_Derivative_is_Increasing).  A function is convex if and only if the derivative is increasing. The essential point here is that the derivative is concave and the function is convex. Just by drawing a graph you can see that the two curves can meet at only one other point other than zero and then diverge from each other.

Comment: The first chain of inequalities in your comment are for $f’$, the derivative. The hypothesis in the problem statement is that $f’$ is itself “concave”. The inequalities should be the reverse of what you wrote. Even if they were the reverse, the inequalities go the other way for the function which must be convex and we still would get a contradiction.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x+%2B+e%5E%28-x%29+-1+and+1-e%5E%28-x%29+from+0+to+10)

Comment: maybe, there exists a different concept on the concave and convex between us. In your opinion, a rainbow in the sky is concave or convex?

Comment: I changed my problem. Can you prove the new version?

Comment: Rainbow would be considered concave.